# Aptana 3 git commit

Tags: git, github, aptana3

I am trying to use git to keep track of any work I do on my current project. So what I want to be able to do is no matter what machine I am on, my laptop or desktop, is pull down the current snapshot of the project, make any changes and add new files then commit it back to the repository.

I am using Aptana 3 and I was able to clone my repository but when I selected all of the files and selected commit, no changes were made to the repository on github.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git has 3 distinct operations that happen in order to put new changes into a remote repository:

1. Changes are `add`ed to the local staging area.
2. The local staging area is `commit`ted.
3. The resulting new local commit is `push`ed to the remote repository.

What you tried to do may have only accomplished #2, which means that nothing was actually committed (due to #1 not having been done). Furthermore, nothing would show up on GitHub until #3 was done as well.